# VBA : Updating a Sheet in a XLA Add-In

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, xla

I'm currently updating a `Worksheet` in the `ActiveWorkbook` on the fly from a network file.

I'd like to move this Ws from the `ActiveWorkbook` into an `XLA Add-In`.

If I do so, will I still be able to update it (ie update the data then save the XLA Add-In) if the XLA Add-In is password-protected ? Would something like this work ?

```
Private Sub updateMyXLASheet(ByVal MyDataArray as Variant)

ThisWorkbook.Sheet("myXLADataSheet").Range("myDataArrayGoesHere").Value = MyDataArray
Application.DislayAlertes = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DislayAlertes = True

End Sub
```

(`ThisWorkbook` being the `XLA Add-In` workbook)

Comment: Pretty easy to test - did you try it?

Comment: @TimWilliams. Thats what I just did succefully :-D. PS : My macro being rather big/complex, I just spend several hours replacing hundreds of `ThisWorkbook` references with the correct `ActiveWorkbook` / `ThisWorkbook` / `myDataWorkbook` ones. (And since it was the first time a was dealing with a complex `XLA Add-In`, it was actually not that easy.) However, I just found Excel will not let me define `Names` in the `ActiveWorkbook` refering to `ThisWorkbook`...

Comment: What happens when you try to add a name?  I just ran this from an add-in with no problem:  `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "Test", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")`

Comment: Actually, I'm able to successfully create `Names` referering to the `XLA Add-In`, but if I save and close the `ActiveWorkbook`, links updating will fail when I open it again... EDIT : It seems like I'm wrong and that the `Names` is indeed working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Excel have no problem updating then saving a Sheet on a password protected XLA Add-In.